# Replace Windows SDI Frame with Dialog Box VS 2019 C++

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog, toolbar

I want to either put a dialog box as a replacement for a SDI Windows frame, or put dialog type controls in the Windows Frame. I don't want a pop up dialog to show up. I would use a dialog based application if I could place a menu and toolbar on the top. They don't seem to be available.

Comment: Please see [ask].

Comment: Dialog based apps do support menus (just add one in the resource editor) and toolbars (see [dlgcbr32](https://github.com/microsoft/VCSamples/tree/master/VC2010Samples/MFC/general/dlgcbr32)).